# How do I get the ID of a newly created record on a custom lightning component?

Tags: apex, javascript, lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps

How do I do that on a custom lightning component? I have a custom form to create a new Case, and now want to grab that Id of a new record and do more with it.

edit: Here is my code:

**Controller**

```
    @AuraEnabled
    public static String saveCase (Case c){
        upsert c;
        return String.ValueOf (c.Id);
    }
```

**Component** (I left out the attribute which defines the new case)

```
    <aura:attribute name="caseId" type="String" />
```

**Javascript Controller**

```
        var newCase = component.get("v.newCase");
        console.log("Create case: " + JSON.stringify(newCase));
        helper.createCase(component, newCase);
```

**Javascript Helper**

```
createCase: function(component, c) {
var action = component.get("c.saveCase");
action.setParams({
    "c": c
});
action.setCallback(this, function(response){
    var state = response.getState();
    if (component.isValid() && state === "SUCCESS") {
        var id = response.getReturnValue();
        component.set("v.caseId",id);
    }
});
$A.enqueueAction(action);
```

Answer (score 1):

After `insert`'ing a record in Apex, the sObject will be updated with the ID. This means that the ID is available in the back-end code. In order to make this available in the component, your controller has to return that ID so that it can be stored in the form.

The code could look like this:

**Lightning component:**

```
<aura:attribute name="caseId" type="String" access="private"/>
```

**Apex controller:**

```
public String CreateCase ()
{
    Case case = new Case();
    // Do stuff with your case
    insert case;
    return String.ValueOf (case.Id);
}
```

**Javascript controller:**

```
createCase: function(component, response) {
    var action = component.get("c.CreateCase");
    action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        if(component.isValid() && response.getState() === "SUCCESS") {
            var responseVal = response.getReturnValue();
            component.set("v.caseId", responseVal);
        });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
}
```

Comment: So I implemented it this way. When I try to do console.log(component.get("v.caseId") on the javascript controller the ID comes out undefined, however the ID is working on the helper. I will update my original question with the code.

Comment: @Alex where in the code are you logging the case ID in the controller? Remember the request to Apex is running asynchronously. So if you fetch the case ID inside the callback inside the helper, you'll find the ID; but if you log `v.caseId` in the controller after calling the helper, the order of execution is: Helper starts -> Helper initates callout -> Helper returns -> Controller logs `v.caseId` which is still null - - - > response comes back from Apex and the callback stores the case in `v.caseId`.

Comment: You have 90% of the code now. As @Charles T mentioned, you might be logging it in the wrong place. Just make sure you log/debug the case ID in the callback to verify you're receiving it OK.

Answer (score 0):

I used this in the javascript controller to solve the problem.

```
event.getParam("response").id
```